# Drag and resize div

Tags: jquery

I found the follwing code, but original code used ID but when i use class its not working? As i use the same class name for different boxes which are drag-gable and re sizable.

```
 $(function() {
            var a = $(".texteditorInitial");
            var b = $('#siteGroup');
            a.draggable({
            drag: function() {
                    if (a.position().top > b.height() - a.height()) {
                        b.height(b.height() + 10);
                    }
                    if (a.position().top < b.height() - a.height()) {
                        b.height(b.height() - 1);
                    }
                }
            });
            var c = $(".title_bar");
            var d = $('#siteGroup');
                c.resizable({
                resize: function() {

                    if (c.offset().top > d.height() - c.height()) {
                        d.height(d.height() + 10);
                    }
                    if (c.offset().top < d.height() - c.height()) {
                        d.height(d.height() - 1);
                    }
                }
            });

        });
```

please help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chetanmani/pEgcA/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think it works

[**Check This Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/39FzG/)

```
<div class="texteditorInitial"></div>
<div id="siteGroup"></div>
<div class="title_bar"></div>
```

Comment: Hi the html structure i have is <div id="siteGroup">


<div class="texteditorInitial title_bar"></div>
    <div class="texteditorInitial title_bar"></div>
</div>

Comment: Add this in fiddle it works only for the first box, but not for the second box

Comment: When you drag or resize the first box, the siteGroup also changes its height, but when you drag or resize the second box siteGroup wont change its height or width.

Comment: I would like to change the siteGroup height and width when you resize or drag the second box as well with same class name

Comment: Welcome. Hope it Helps

Comment: one last question is it possible to containment the box to the width of siteGroup. So that it wont go out of siteGroup side ways

Comment: I tried many things. but i cant able to make much smoother. Now see this. http://jsfiddle.net/39FzG/9/ when i have time i will update.